# Exporting Date field and Drop Down to IE

Tags: vba

I am trying to populate some 15 odd fields to IE through VBA and have the below code. While all text fields are being pouplated, I am unable to populate the date fields and drop down field.

```
Private Sub CommandButton4_Click()
    Dim IE As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
    Dim URL As String

    URL = Sheet1.Range("A1").Value

    Set IE = GetIEWindow2
    If IE Is Nothing Then
        Set IE = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
    End If

    With IE
        .Visible = True


    IE.Document.all(Sheet1.Range("F6").Value).Value = Sheet1.Range("B10").Value
    IE.Document.all(Sheet1.Range("G6").Value).Value = Sheet1.Range("B11").Value
    IE.Document.all(Sheet1.Range("H6").Value).Checked = True 'Entered
    IE.Document.all(Sheet1.Range("I6").Value).Checked = True 'Entered
    IE.Document.all(Sheet1.Range("J6").Value).Value = Sheet1.Range("B14").Value
    IE.Document.all(Sheet1.Range("K6").Value).Value = Sheet1.Range("B15").Value
    IE.Document.all(Sheet1.Range("L6").Value).Value = Sheet1.Range("B16").Value
    IE.Document.all(Sheet1.Range("M6").Value).Value = Sheet1.Range("B17").Value
    IE.Document.all(Sheet1.Range("N6").Value).Value = Sheet1.Range("B18").Value 'for date in the format 28/04/2015 00:00:00
    IE.Document.all(Sheet1.Range("O6").Value).Value = Sheet1.Range("B19").Value
    IE.Document.all(Sheet1.Range("P6").Value).Value = Sheet1.Range("B20").Value
    IE.Document.all(Sheet1.Range("Q6").Value).Value = Sheet1.Range("B21").Value
    **IE.Document.all(Sheet1.Range("R6").Value).Value = Sheet1.Range("B22").Value** 'this is for drop down

    End With

End Sub


Private Function GetIEWindow2() As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer

    'Look for an IE browser window and, if found, return that browser as an InternetExplorer object.  Otherwise return Nothing

    Dim Shell As Object
    Dim IE As Object
    Dim i As Variant 'Must be a Variant to index Shell.Windows.Item() array

    Set Shell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

    i = 0
    Set GetIEWindow2 = Nothing
    While i < Shell.Windows.Count And GetIEWindow2 Is Nothing
        Set IE = Shell.Windows.Item(i)
        If Not IE Is Nothing Then
            Debug.Print IE.LocationURL, IE.LocationName
            If TypeName(IE) = "IWebBrowser2" Then
                If TypeOf IE Is SHDocVw.InternetExplorer And IE.LocationURL <> "" And InStr(IE.LocationURL, "file://") <> 1 Then
                    Set GetIEWindow2 = IE
                End If
            End If
        End If
        i = i + 1
    Wend

End Function
```